# Java strings compare getText()

Tags: java, string, selenium, compare, equals

I have two strings, one is:
`String currentDoc= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".active .ng-scope:nth-child(2)")).getText();`

and the outcome of it is:

```
First Name Last Name Remove Worker details
Goran Dxxxxxc
David Vxxxxć
Matija Mxxxxc
Andrej Txxxxk
```

second string is:

```
String docList = "First Name Last Name Remove Worker details\r\n" + 
                "Goran Dxxxxxc\r\n" + 
                "David Vxxxxć\r\n" + 
                "Matija Mxxxxc\r\n" + 
                "Andrej Txxxxk";
```

when I do:
`System.out.println(trenutniPopis.equals(currentDoc));`
I always get *false*
First I thought "ć" was the problem but replacing it with "c" in both cases made no difference.
Any thoughts what could be the problem?
thank you

Comment: Does the actual string indeed contain `\r\n` line endings? Check the details: use a debugger to look at what exactly the first string contains, and see what's different with what you're comparing it with.

Answer (score 2):

New line can be represented by multiple characters:

- `\r\n`
- `\n`
- `\r`.

I would recommend to use regex.

```
String regex = "First Name Last Name Remove Worker details\\s+" + 
                "Goran Dxxxxxc\\s+" + 
                "David Vxxxxć\\s+" + 
                "Matija Mxxxxc\\s+" + 
                "Andrej Txxxxk";

System.out.println(currentDoc.matches(regex));
```

`\s` - matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times